# how to exclude field execution from method executions pointcut with Aspectj

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'd like to capture all method executions. So I defined below pointcut and tried to exclude the field access with get/set pointcut designators, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

```
 pointcut funcExecutionPointcut():execution(* *.*(..)) && !get(* *.*) && !set(* *.*);

   before():funcExecutionPointcut()     {

             //log some info.   
             Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
              String className = "";
        if (thisJoinPoint.getThis() != null)
            className = thisJoinPoint.getThis().getClass().getName();
            mylogger.log(Level.INFO,"Entering [(" + className + ")" + sig.toShortString() + "] @" + line + "@" +file);
 }
```

The problem is that the output shows that the class's fields are also hit by the pointcut, log like below.

```
2013-09-30 11:39:11:18  Thread-447      INFO AspectJFuncTracing - Entering [()ImageListManager.access$0(..)] @48@ImageListManager.java
2013-09-30 11:39:11:19  Thread-447      INFO AspectJFuncTracing - Entering [()ImageListManager.access$1(..)] @56@ImageListManager.java
```

The corresponding source code is as below.

```
    ....
    public void run() {

        while (mThreadBeing) {
            try {
                sleep(sleeptime);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sleeptime = 200;
            if (!mThreadBeing) {
                break;
            }
            if (mScrolling) {
                continue;
            }
                            ...
```

ImageListManager.access$0 points to the class field mThreadBeing, while ImageListManager.access$1 points to the class field mScrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the synthetic methods executions, they are created by compiler because, I suppose from what you wrote down, the *run()* method is inside an inner class of your **ImageListManager**. They are in charge of retrieving the values for the first and the second defined field (supposing from the $0 and the $1 after the access).

If you want to remove that executions put in you pointcut and and-clause with:

```
!execution(* *.access$*(..))
```

Hope it helps,

Dario.